# For reach UI Design of iPhone Application

Tags: iphone

I'm looking an e-book or some example/samples/tutorials for reach GUI implementation with 3d animation in an iPhone Application.

If anybody has any references then could you please let me know..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should read Bill Dudney's [Core Animation for Mac OS X and the iPhone: Creating Compelling Dynamic User Interfaces](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone) book before start planning your 3D animations on Iphone.